# Mapping Normal distribution to a new bounded distribution.

Tags: probability, soft-question

My question is vague. I am looking for distributions that can be obtained from [Normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) by mapping it to a bounded interval.
"By mapping" I mean that a probability distribution function(PDF) is obtained from PDF for Normal distribution by applying some function. For example, [log normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) distribution is obtained from Normal distribution by using exponential function.
What distribution do you know that obtained from Normal distribution by mapping to a bounded interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every distribution on $\mathbb R$ (or on any interval of $\mathbb R$) is the distribution of a random variable $H(X)$, where the random variable $X$ is standard normal, for some nondecreasing function $H$.

*Proof:* Let $F$ denote the CDF of the desired distribution and $G$ the standard gaussian CDF. Then $G(X)$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ and, for every $U$ uniform on $(0,1)$, $F^{-1}(U)$ has CDF $F$. The inverse $F^{-1}$ must be defined with care when the CDF $F$ of the target distribution is not increasing but only nondecreasing, but this can be done, and it works. By composition $H=F^{-1}\circ G$ fits.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the question makes much sense because of this:

Let $X$ be any continuous random variable (bounded or not) and $F_X$ its CDF. Then the random variable $U=F_X(X)$ has uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

Now pick *any* other continuous random variable (bounded or not), say $Y$ and let $F_Y$ be the corresponding CDF. Then the random variable $F_Y^{-1}(U)$ has the same distribution as $Y$ has.

Concluding, if you pick $X$ to be normal, you can generate any arbitrary continuous distribution $F_Y$ by considering the random variable, $$F_Y^{-1}\left(F_X(X)\right).$$

Comment: Your answer is awesome. I had to choose the answer by Did, because he answered earlier (and the essence is the same).

Comment: When I started typing he had not answered, if I knew someone was already working on it, I would pass. It was not my intention to replicate someone else answer.

Comment: Yes, I know that ( I was in this situation :-) ) I just feel bad about not accepting two good answers.