# Probability Integral Transform

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I've been applying the probability integral transform as shown here:

[Mapping CDF's to each other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592076/mapping-cdfs-to-each-other?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I want to standardise the data that is wiebull distibuted by mapping it to standard normal:

The original histogram is shown below:

[image: Original Histogram]

When I transform to the standard Normal I get the histogram shown below, which doesn't look very Normal. I don't want the big gap I want the transformed histogram to look as much like a standard normal as possible. Is there anything else I can do?

[image: Transformed Data]